# How to use the continuationtoken in TFS 2015 Object Model: GetBuildsAsync?

Tags: tfs-2015

I am using the following code

```
    BuildHttpClient service = new BuildHttpClient(tfsCollectionUri, 
new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials(true));

    var asyncResult = service.GetBuildsAsync(project: tfsTeamProject);
    var queryResult = asyncResult.Result;
```

This returns only the first 199 builds.

Looks like in need to use the [continuationtoken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) but am not sure how to do this. The docs say that the REST API will return the token.  I am using the Object Model, and am looking for how to retrieve the token!

I am using Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client v 14.102.0; Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient v 14.102.0, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Service.Client v 14.102.0 and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient v 14.102.0

**Question**
**How do I use the continuation token **when using the TFS Object model?**

Answer (score 1):

The continuationToken is in the response header after the first call to the API:

```
x-ms-continuationtoken: xxxx
```

It can not be retrieved from .net client library. You have to use the rest api to retrieve the header information. Here is an example for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetBuilds
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task t = GetBuilds();
            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t });
        }
        private static async Task GetBuilds()
        {
            try
            {
                var username = "xxxxx";
                var password = "******";

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                                "http://tfs2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamproject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.2").Result)
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'GetBuildsAsync2', which returns an IPagedList. You can retrieve the ContinuationToken from the IPagedList:

```
        // Iterate to get the full set of builds
        string continuationToken = null;
        List<Build> builds = new List<Build>();
        do
        {
            IPagedList<Build> buildsPage = service.GetBuildsAsync2(tfsTeamProject, continuationToken: continuationToken).Result;

            //add the builds
            builds.AddRange(buildsPage);

            //get the continuationToken for the next loop
            continuationToken = buildsPage.ContinuationToken;
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);
```